# URL cannot be found for .jpg files

Tags: image, url, http-status-code-404

Just uploaded a website and it works fine on my own webspace and locally but on the live domain any image thumbnails that I click direct to the raw image itself which will open in the viewport but I am getting a URL cannot be found (`404 error`)

I have checked my document paths and all are lower case. I must stress this is working on my own domain just not the domain I have been given to upload. I am clueless.... Is it `.htaccess` or `httpd.conf`?

The domain toolbox is cpanel. The address is lynehamaviation.co.uk but because there is a maintenance page at `index.html`. The best angle of entry is  [www.lynehamaviation.co.uk/members.html](http://lynehamaviation.co.uk/members.html)

Comment: Check if it is a problem with case sensitivity: .jpg vs. .JPG

Comment: Was indeed thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend that you set up an FTP account for your website (you can do this from your CPanel), and use an FTP client (such as [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/)). From there, log in to your FTP account, navigate to your `public_html` folder, and find the path that contains your gallery images. Upload the missing files there and you should be good to go!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi I do use FileZilla to upload :) I will try fully re-uploading the site and may even set up a subdomain in cpanel to see if there is some permission issue elsewhere

Comment: The only reason you'll get a 404 error is if the file isn't on the server. It looks like you managed to get one image uploaded, but the rest didn't go through. Try re-uploading just the `images/gallery/general` folder. No need to re-upload the whole site :)

Comment: Actually thanks! I have just followed your advice and checked the public_html directory itself and noticed that half of the images were not uploaded correctly and gave themselves an upper case JPG extension causing the 404. Am remedying now.

Cannot thank you enough for pointing me in the right direction.
Tom

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck with your website! It looks good so far!

Comment: Thank you very much :) All self-taught and using Notepad++ so far!

Answer (score 0):

If the files exists on the web servers you should check that the server is set up to serve files with the jpg extension.

Comment: Thanks for this. Some of the images do work. 1 or 2 per page load correctly when clicked. But the majority just 404 out when clicked.